# Mobile view set from a specific width using viewport

Tags: html, viewport

i saw there is similar questions here but as I am kind of a n00b I didn't found the answer.

Using viewport, how can i say to my website this:

`if width >= 1024 the width = viewport
else if width >= 480 the width = mobile
else width = viewport.`

Basically, between infinity and 1024 --> desktop view
lower than 1024 --> mobile view.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {**DESKTOP CODE**}
```

Everything under 1024px is your mobile view. That's the CSS-Code outside of the @media query.

In terms of mobile-view: Check out https://www.mydevice.io/ to get the right widths.

Comment: I dont know why this doesnt seem to work. I have a layout page for mobile and a layout for desktop, I juste want the limit to be 1024 between one and the other but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Well, that's the solution you would go with. Maybe you can provide a link to your site for a deeper look.